# GeoServer clustering JMS extension problems

Tags: geoserver, clustering

I am new to GeoServer Active Clustering. If having two GeoServer instances (2.22.0) running locally in Jetty, i.e.:

localhost:8080/geoserver

localhost:8090/geoserver

When installing the **JMS extension** for both of them, I am not able to make them talk to each other.

I just simply changed in the `cluster.properties`:

`toggleSlave=false` for the MASTER geoserver (port 8080)

and

`toggleMaster=false` for the SLAVE geoserver (port 8090)

but the configuration, or data, from the MASTER does not seem to be transferred to the SLAVE.

Besides, every time I want to go and change something in the configuration via web-GUI, the session gets expired in the GeoServer that was not being updated, so I have to continuously log in.

What I am missing here as a start?